# RStudio and devtools do not install static vignettes

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I created an R package for an introductory course in remote sensing with R ([github link](https://github.com/joergsteinkamp/FEglobaleOekologie)) and want to provide the handouts as as static PDF vignettes (copy protected) as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf).  With the standard Linux commandline "R CMD build FEglobaleOekologie && R CMD INSTALL FEglobaleOekologie_0.0.1.tar.gz" everything works fine. However, when I install it from within my RStudio project or under MS Windows with devtools::install_github" there are no vignettes. The later one is the target platform, where I would like to have them.

Sadly I could not find any thread, that solves my problem. Can anyone tell what's going wrong here or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into problems like this, too. I've found that build doesn't always build my vignettes (that generally happens with using build in the RStudio menu, since I believe that doesn't include the vignettes by default ). You might want to try also running `build_vignettes()` before uploading to GitHub;  and when installing from GitHub, explicitly including `build_vignettes = TRUE` in the `install_github` function.  Otherwise, you may have a path issue for the installed package.

Comment: Thanks, that was it already. I also had to disable Vignettes in Build -> More -> "Configure build Tools ..." -> "Generate documentation with roxygen". Otherwise the effect of build_vignettes() would have been reverted again.

Comment: I was looking forward too early ;-( It worked from within rstudio now, but not with install_guthub on a Windows machine. Neither with option build_vignettes=TRUE nor FALSE.